# Where is cdb.exe located in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to configure a debugger for Qt Creator. However, I can't find cdb.exe. From internet, I found out that it is supposed to be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe`. Yet, I don't have directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers`. I do have a directory called `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64` but it only contains files `dbghelp.dll`, `srcsrv.dll` and `symsrv.dll`.

Comment: It's normally something you download as part of the Windows SDK, did you do this? You can get it from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I thought it comes with Visual Studio. Let me try that.

Comment: The other dlls you refer to are part of Windows and have been since Windows 2000 I believe, cdb.exe and the gui version windbg.exe were always part of the debugging tools for Windows which has to be installed separately AFAIK

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cdb.exe and the gui equivalent windbg.exe are part of the debugging tools for windows and have to be downloaded as part of the windows SDK, in the past it has been part of the DDK also.

You can get it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx

If you're just interested in the tools there is a link for the standalone debugging tools (as part of windows 8.1 SDK) here: https://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_EAC=300135395

dbghelp.dll, srcsrv.dll and symsrv.dll are shipped as part of Windows and has been since Windows 2000 (I think this is certainly true of dbghelp.dll).